testcontainers.kafka with Python
I was trying to run below code in my local and getting dockerexception,do we need to actually install docker locally to use testcontainers for integration testing for our kafka topics?
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, 
KafkaProducer, TopicPartition
from testcontainers.kafka import 
KafkaContainer


def test_kafka_producer_consumer():
    with KafkaContainer() as container:
       produce_and_consume_kafka_message(container)


def produce_and_consume_kafka_message(container):


    topic = 'test-topic'
    bootstrap_server = 
    container.get_bootstrap_server()

    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=[bootstrap_server])
    producer.send(topic, b"verification message")
    producer.flush()
    producer.close()

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=[bootstrap_server])
    tp = TopicPartition(topic, 0)
    consumer.assign([tp])
    consumer.seek_to_beginning()
    assert consumer.end_offsets([tp])[tp] == 1, \
        "Expected exactly one test message to be present on test topic!"

Below is the error that I'm getting:
Pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

 ..\..\py31lvenv\Lib\sitepackages\docker\transport\npipesocket.py:54: error

The above exception was the direct 
causeof the following exception:

  @pytest fixture (scope='module')

  def kafka_container():

     with KafkaContainer() as container:
      test_kafka.py:13:

Invalid response from docker daemon: key "ApiVersion"

Exise DockerException

f'Error while fetching server API version:
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.

I would need help here, how we can actually run testcontainers for integration testing of kafka?

This error happens when Testcontainers cannot find the default DOCKER_HOST. The fix depends on how do you run Docker. For example, on M-based MacBook running Colima adding this environment variable helps (assuming that Colima has its socket in the ${HOME}/.colima directory.
export DOCKER_HOST="unix://${HOME}/.colima/default/docker.sock"

You need to set the DOCKER_HOST variable to whatever your Docker socket is.
